# Инкремент, декремент

Tags: c++

добрый день, вопрос такой, почему нельзя сделать так:

i++++;

Но можно так:

++++i;

Comment: Есть унарный плюс (перед выражением). А вот унарного плюса после выражения в C/C++ вроде не было.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

разница в том, что возвращают постфиксная и префиксная формы инкремента. Префиксная возвращает ссылку на инкрементированную переменную i, а префиксная возвращает не ссылку, а значение некоторой временной переменной, в которой было сохранено предыдущее (до инкремента) значение переменной i.
Выглядит это примерно так (для int) :

```
int& operator ++(int& a);​      // префиксная форма
​int operator ++(int& a, int);​  // постфиксная форма
```

В первом случае значение, возвращаемое оператором инкремента является lvalue, во втором - не является

Comment: Не буду говорить за C++, а вот что касается старого доброго...

     #include <stdio.h>
     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       int i;
       ++i = 5;
       printf("%d\n", i);
     }

     a.c: В функции «main»:
     a.c:4:9: ошибка: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

А в C++ -- там да, программа транслируется. Страшненький язык, однако.

Comment: @alexlz: В C++ более одного обращения на запись в пределах одной логической единицы (более точно — между двумя последовательными sequence point, не знаю, как это на русском) является undefined behaviour.

Comment: "И эти люди не разрешают мне ковырять в носу"... Сложный язык. Почти как перл. А может и сложнее. Нормальный инструмент должен быть проще.

Comment: @alexlz: во многом сложность C++ вызвана желанием обеспечить обратную совместимость с C, причём на уровне синтаксиса. Отсюда, например, наличие как указателей, так и ссылок, как нуль-терминированных строк, так и std::string, как макросов, так и шаблонов. Всё это увеличивает сложность языка.

Comment: @VladD Это ответ на вопрос "почему так?". А как насчёт вопроса "зачем?" ("а нафига такое счастье?")

Comment: @alexlz: Тут остаётся лишь предполагать. Например, [так](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/picture.html#fqa-6.2).

Comment: @VladD Maybe. Но, как писал А.Москаль "чайник с C++ куда опаснее чайника с VB".